# How can I disable or change the shortcut for snipping tool in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, snipping, 1password

Microsoft Edge appears to have a version of "Snipping Tool" in the browser. You can use it with the shortcut "Ctrl + Shift + X".  I don't have any need for this and the shortcut also conflicts with the default shortcut for 1Password.  Does anyone know how to either disable the "Snipping Tool" feature or deactivate it so there isn't a conflict?  The closest thing I've found to do is change the shortcut for 1Password.  I'd rather not change the shortcut there though.

Comment: Most Apps with hot keys have options to change to co-exist with Microsoft. That is how I do this. I understand you don't wish to change but it is probably the easiest way forward.

Comment: I use 1Password daily on the current version of Edge. Are you positive you don’t have an extension installed? I have no conflict with 1Password

Comment: In fact [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-edge-50d3edab-30d9-c7e4-21ce-37fe2713cfad) suggests there isn’t such a keyboard shortcut for Edge

Comment: [Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10) shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

> How can I disable or change the shortcut for snipping tool in
> Microsoft Edge?

Microsoft does make all this information to Software Vendors in advance (Microsoft Insider and other like programs).

So Software Vendors make their Hot Keys readily changeable (SnagIT, VMware and so on).

Changing your App is the easiest way forward - I have done this for a very long time.

It is easier than trying to change Microsoft.

**Note:**  For Snipping tool, I used the Microsoft offering of WinKey - Shift -S and that alternative works for Snipping tool.

Comment: I made a NOTE in my answer that I use WinKey - Shift -S for Snipping tool and that appears to be unique with respect to other Hot Keys on my machine (that is, no other app uses WinKey - Shift -S)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been signaled in the 1Password Community post
[CTRL-SHIFT-X shortcut being used by Microsoft Edge v90+](https://1password.community/discussion/120730/ctrl-shift-x-shortcut-being-used-by-microsoft-edge-v90#:%7E:text=Starting%20in%20version%2090%2B%20of,override%20the%20Edge%20feature%20shortcut).

The answer on May 2021 was:

> We are aware of this issue and are looking into the best course of action without affecting other browsers that use the same code base (e.g. any other Chromium based browser).

Ensure you are using the latest version of 1Password.
If the problem is still there, you could join the above
1Password Community linked post, or ask in your own new post why
the problem is not being addressed.

In the meantime, see if 1Password has an option to change its
shortcut, to say, Alt+Shift+X.
If that's possible and you wish to remain with the old shortcut,
you could use a product such as
[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
to map Ctrl+Shift+X to Alt+Shift+X and Alt+Shift+X to Ctrl+Shift+X
in Edge.